# Java DateFormat isn't parsing my with my SimpleDateFormat correctly

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm using the following SimpleDateFormat

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSSSS");
```

And then reading in my timestamp with, where timeStamp is a string like this 29/May/2013:09:12:06.80652 and this.timestamp is a Date

```
    this.timestamp = dateFormat.parse(timeStamp);
```

I can't understand why, when I go to output timestamp and use it for timestamp comparison, the times are changed- given that date above, my output is

```
    Timestamp before dateFormat: 29/May/2013:09:12:06.80625
    Timestamp after dateFormat: Wed May 29 09:13:26 EDT 2013
```

I don't care about the EDT and other formatting, what I can't understand is how the time goes from 9:12:06 to 9:13:26.

Thanks!

Comment: 80625ms give actually 1min20sec more so 9:12:06 > 9:13:26

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie That's an answer really.

Comment: Ohhh... and google tells me I'm on my own when it comes to handling microseconds. Gaah! Thanks though!

Comment: @winepretzel is your timestamp source 5 digits or 6 digits microseconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your format is taking microseconds as milliseconds so your 80625 is converted in minutes and seconds (1min20sec = 80000ms).

You should truncate microseconds and flush 3 least significant numbers.

This will work :

```
DateFormat oDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMMMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String sDate = "29/May/2013:09:12:06.80625";
long lMicroseconds;

// Computing milliseconds from microseconds since it the number of digits can change
lMicroseconds = Long.valueOf(sDate.substring(sDate.indexOf('.') + 1,sDate.length()));
sDate = sDate.substring(0,sDate.indexOf('.')) + "." + (lMicroseconds / 1000);

System.out.println(oDateFormat.parse(sDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to take the milliseconds into account, and 80625 milliseconds are more or less 80 secondes, or 1 minute and 20 seconds.

9:12:06 + 1:20 => 9:13:26

If you want to handle them, you may take a look at the `Calendar` and `TimeUnit` API.

Answer (score 0):

80625 is exactly 1min and 20 seconds more. So this is how you get the change, it just adds the milliseconds.